# Rewrite options InheritDown* behave weirdly in subdirectories and subdomains on LiteSpeed server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, litespeed

I was trying to host two *separate* sites, using the main domain like `[www.]example.com` and one subdomain `sub.example.com`, on a *shared* hosting environment powered by LiteSpeed. The document root of the subdomain is `public_html/sub/` but its contents should *not* be accessed through `example.com/sub/...`.

Initially I wrote a rule with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]` in `public_html/sub/.htaccess` to forbid wrong requests, which seemed to work.
But obviously, I will have to repeat this rule for each subdomain when there are more. Besides, the directories of the main domain were mixed with the subdomains. Therefore, I moved the files of the main domain to `public_html/www/` directory, added the following lines in the following `.htaccess` files and removed the rule wrote before.

In `public_html/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore

RewriteRule ^ /www%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

In `public_html/www/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions IgnoreInherit
...
```

According to [the doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteOptions), I supposed the rule would "change" the document root of the main domain to `public_html/www/` as it is evaluated first and stops rewriting in any directory (as long as subdirectories do not turn off rewrite engine or ignore inheritance), while subdomains would not inherit rules from directories outside their document roots (`public_html/.htaccess`), thus not affected.

However, after changing `example.com/sub/...` actually are still accessible, just like `InheritDown*` are not supported by LiteSpeed. Even more strangely, valid URLs in `sub.example.com` will get not-found error, indicating they might be rewritten becaused of the inherited rule. I'm not sure if it is LiteSpeed's bug and should I report a problem. Or, did I misunderstand the option?

By the way, is there any alternative solution to implement the same function?

Comment: but what about just set up different vhost for each of them?  with its own docroot

Comment: Is this a _shared_ server environment?

Comment: @qtwrk It is a shared hosting server, and I can't set up new virtual hosts or change the document root of the main domain. I think I can only use the subdomain function provided in cPanel to add more domains.

Comment: @MrWhite Yes. I can't change the main domain and may only use the subdomain function provided in cPanel to add more domains.

Comment: When you create sub in cpanel, it will create its own vhost,  just point the path to it when you create it

Comment: @qtwrk It seems that cPanel only allows creating subdomains or addon domains under `public_html/`. I still can't make new sites independent of the main domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying more rules and comparing them with a standard Apache server, I'm basically sure the inherit feature is *very* buggy in LiteSpeed, and also I found a workaround to meet my needs. I'll just answer my question, but I think there're still better solutions (and expect new answers).

First, I found that rewrite option `InheritBefore` behaves just like `Inherit` in LiteSpeed (inherited rules are still placed at last). And instead of preventing inheritance, `IgnoreInherit` actually also does like `Inherit` in LiteSpeed. `InheritDown*` randomly worked sometimes, but most of time it did not.
Considering these weird problems, maybe **it's better to just avoid using inheritance on LiteSpeed servers**.

> Subdomains would not inherit rules from directories outside their document roots, thus not affected.

Besides I have to clarify `Inherit*` in fact make sense for subdomains on both servers. Because of that, rewrite conditions should be added to `public_html/.htaccess` to avoid affecting subdomains:
(*For standard Apache servers, this will be enough to separate the main domain.*)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore

# added
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /www%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

And as `InheritDown*` may not work in subdirectories containing `.htaccess`, one line still needs to be added to the `.htaccess` of each subdirectory:

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
```

However, since this workaround is not neat either, it might be better to keep the previous practice before finding better ones.